# Python cannot import py files in the same folder

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.41.1
- OS Version:Ubuntu 18.04

Steps to Reproduce:

```sh
# tree:
.
├── demo1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test.py
├── __init__.py
├── auto.py
```

```py
# auto.py
def func():
    print("1")
```

```
# test.py
from auto import func

func()
```

Use examples to solve problems that arise in a project
Run the test.py file, and I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func'"
I used 'CTRL '+ left mouse button in test.py to jump to func
The same code can be run in pycharm

Comment: working directory has to be the root of the file tree, i do not know how to set it in visual studio code (imported modules are imported relative to the working directory when you just run a file)

Comment: Please note, that importing from outside the package is almost always a bad idea. It involves messing with relative imports, which is, well... messy. Always try to structurize your project to avoid such problems. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run test.py directly then you need to add the parent folder to PYTHONPATH. Try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..\<parent_folder>")
from auto import func
```

Otherwise, if you merely want to import test.py in another .py file, you can use relative import of python

```
from . import auto #another dot '.' to go up two packages
auto.func()
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: Thank you. I just transferred from pycharm to vscode. Previous projects could run without introducing sys, but this one had problems

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-line solution

```
from ... import auto
```

and call the function by using `auto.func()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in test.py, before import:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/project/root/directory")
```

For me it's not a good file organization. A better practice might be as below:

Let your project file tree be like:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── lib
│   ├── auto.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

And write test.py like:

```py
from lib.auto import func

func()
```